# Enclosures and for loops in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've visited quite a lot of Stack Overflow answers on this topic and none of the answers seem to work for me. I'm adding listeners to objects in a for-loop, but all my listener code only gets applied to the last loop. I read up about enclosures and this was the approach I tried, but I'm still having the problem:

```
for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    var beach = beaches[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2]},
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      shape: shape,
      title: beach[0],
      zIndex: beach[3]
    });
    var contentString = contentstrings[i];
    function makeItHappenDelegate() {
       return function(){
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
                    });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    };
marker.addListener('click',makeItHappenDelegate());


  }
```

which means that the function makeItHappenDelegate() gets applied as the function to execute on all my markers.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you copied that solution correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to capture the value of `contentString` and `marker`, you can do it like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    var beach = beaches[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {
            lat: beach[1],
            lng: beach[2]
        },
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        shape: shape,
        title: beach[0],
        zIndex: beach[3]
    });

    var contentString = contentstrings[i];

    function makeItHappenDelegate(contentString, marker) {
        return function() {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
            });
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    };
    marker.addListener('click', makeItHappenDelegate(contentString, marker));

}
```